# Gradle build fails on news mac

Tags: macos, gradle

I try to compile my Gradle/Kotline Project on my new Mac and getting the same error 'Resource not found'-like errors for all my gradle projects. Any ideas whats wrong? The same project for example works on the latest Docker 'primetoninc/jdk'.

```
mac:nextlevel2017-kotline robert.rajakone$ ./gradlew build
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod (file:/Users/robert.rajakone/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.5.1-all/42vjebfdws9pjts3l4bouoq0p/gradle-3.5.1/lib/gradle-base-services-3.5.1.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.getPackages()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
:compileKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web//spring-boot-starter-web-.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web//spring-boot-starter-web-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web//spring-boot-starter-web-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web//spring-boot-starter-web-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web//spring-boot-starter-web-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web//spring-boot-starter-web-.jar
  Required by:
      project :
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:.
  Required by:
      project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.354 secs
mac:nextlevel2017-kotline robert.rajakone$ uname -a
Darwin mac 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
mac:nextlevel2017-kotline robert.rajakone$ ./gradlew -version
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/Users/robert.rajakone/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.5.1-all/42vjebfdws9pjts3l4bouoq0p/gradle-3.5.1/lib/groovy-all-2.4.10.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-06-16 14:36:27 UTC
Revision:     d4c3bb4eac74bd0a3c70a0d213709e484193e251

Groovy:       2.4.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          9 (Oracle Corporation 9+181)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64

mac:nextlevel2017-kotline robert.rajakone$
```

Comment: upgrade to newest gradle doesn't help (./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=4.2.1)

Comment: What version of Java are you using? i.e. what is the output of `gradle -version`

Comment: Gradle 3.5.1

java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)